# qt - send signal between objects in a class with different parents

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, signals-slots

I have a class ("controller" for example) 
and in this class, I have created many objects of different other classes
 with different parents.

How to send signal between that classes and "controller" to call a function in "controller" class?

```
    #include "controller.h"


    Controller::Controller(QObject *parent) : QObject (parent){
        connect(sender(), SIGNAL(recivedCall(QString)), this, SLOT(alert(QString)));
    }

    void Controller::onCall(QJsonObject callinfo){
         nodes[callinfo["username"].toString()]= new PanelManager();
         nodes[callinfo["username"].toString()]->handleCallStateChanged(callinfo);
    }

    void Controller::alert(QString callinfo){
        qDebug()<<callinfo;
    }
```

For example, how to send signal from  "recivedCall" in each "PanelManager" object to call "alert" function in "controller" class ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The object which creates your two components has to set the connections between your signal and your slot. But, you shouldn't expose inner components (i.e. create getter to return a pointer on a attribute).

A way to tackle the last problem with Qt is to create a signal in your parent and let it broadcast the calls.
For example, if I need to connect a QCheckBox to a QLineEdit in two different widgets:

```
class Parent1: public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    Parent1(): QWidget(), myCheckBox(new QCheckBox("Edit", this))
    {
        connect(myCheckBox, &QCheckBox::clicked, this, &Parent1::editForbidden);
    }
private:
    QCheckBox* myCheckBox;
signals:
    void editForbidden(bool);
};


class Parent2: public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    Parent2(): QWidget(), myLineEdit(new QLineEdit("Edit", this))
    {
        connect(this, &Parent2::forbidEdit, myLineEdit, &QLineEdit::setReadOnly);
    }
private:
    QLineEdit* myLineEdit;
signals:
    void forbidEdit(bool);
};


// In the parent of Parent1 and Parent2 (or in the main if there is no parent)
QObject::connect(p1, &Parent1::editForbidden, p2, &Parent2::forbidEdit);
```

In this example, when I click on the checkbox in `parent1`, the lineEdit in `parent2` is disabled. But, Parent1 doesn't know anything about Parent2.